# Capture piped sed expression to variable

Tags: bash, sed, centos

This is the echo that prints the string I want to capture onto a variable or explicitly append to the PATH variable

```
echo "$(nvm which 5.3.0)"| sed 's/bin\/node$/lib/'
```

I think the capture of the "$nvm which 5.3.0" component is preventing me from wrapping the entire expression with $(...stuff...).

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var="$(nvm which 5.3.0 | sed 's/bin\/node$/lib/')"
```

or

```
var="$(nvm which 5.3.0 | sed 's|bin/node$|lib|')"
```

Comment: as i am sure you know, ut the public might not, they both work.

Comment: Why are you capturing the command $() inside of quotations? Merely asking to broaden my own knowledge.

Comment: @bluerojo: to save successive whitespaces (e.g.).

Comment: @Cyrus: I figured that was the reason, I just didn't think that needed to be done when setting variables via $(). I am still learning as I go along though so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Cyrus answered your first question, so I figured I would add in an answer for your question of **append to the PATH variable**:

Going off of Cyrus's answer of;

```
var="$(nvm which 5.3.0 | sed 's/bin\/node$/lib/')"
```

which sets the ${var} variable, you would then run the following command to **append to the PATH variable**

```
PATH=$PATH:${var}
```

Comment: or `PATH="$PATH:${var}"`